# How to handle answers that should be comments but the answerer doesn't have enough reputation

Tags: discussion

For example, I was presented with a review opportunity for https://stackoverflow.com/a/24066776/2317829.

I feel the answer should clearly be a comment (if anything), but as the answerer doesn't have enough reputation s/he can only answer or not contribute to the discussion.

Specifically in the context of a review, how do you handle this?

I feel a downvote is a bit of a harsh welcome.  And a comment along the lines of "this should be a comment and not an answer" will only result in the answerer or other users pointing out that the answerer's reputation is too low -- that doesn't seem productive.

Comment: Users without sufficient reputation to comment should refrain from commenting.

Comment: The problem is when asking for clarification. There isn't a way for a sub-50 user to do that.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/189840

Answer (score 12):

When reviewing this: **flag it**.

In most cases, the comment will not provide any useful information, so in those cases simply flag it as **Not an Answer**, as it's intended to be a comment. The post will then be put into another review queue to be deleted.

*However*, if you feel that the post does provide some *useful* information, flag it as **other** and explain that it should be converted to a comment. Please provide information such as what post it should be converted to a comment on.

Comment: If you feel it has some value even though it is not an answer, put it where it belongs and then delete the non-answer. The mods are very reluctant to make non-answers comments.

Comment: Agree with Deduplicator--I'm new to reviewing but I've already seen some "answers" by new users which were not answers but would have been really good comments and were a benefit for the question. I guess simply adding them as a comment myself with attribution to the original author and then flagging it would the way to go.  I do remember how hard it was to get those first 50 rep and it felt like ages before I could comment, so I do have sympathy with new users who have no other recourse to contribute their comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in the Low Quality Posts, there's a deletion reason specifically for the case of an answer stating that the post is stating that they have the same problem.

If you're in any of the other review queues, flag the post as Not an Answer to put it into the queue.

If you want to downvote, you certainly can, as the post is not a useful answer.  If you don't, then I suppose that's fine, so long as you aren't upvoting the answer, as that is encouraging inappropriate behavior.

The fact that a user doesn't have enough reputation to post comments doesn't make it any more appropriate to post comments as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Flag as not an answer, comment if you want, downvote if you feel like (possibly only temporarily) spending a rep point.