# My Answers and Edits keep getting rejected - reason - should have been a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, comments

I have been on Stack Overflow for about a month now, but have only asked one question because either I found the answer here, or my problem was too specific to the proprietary tools I am using.

In order to get my reputation up I am trying to provide answers to peoples questions, but many times **I realise** that my "answer or edit" is more of a comment, but I can't add a comment because my reputation isn't over 50.

So in the past few days I have had an Answer and an Edit marked down\rejected because of the reason that "this should be a comment" - but it is clear to these people reviewing me that my reputation doesn't allow me to comment. The most verbose answer I got was "there's a reason why people without enough reputation can't comment..." but then this person didn't actually provide that reason and deleted my Answer.

I get a real feeling from "experienced" users of SO that newbs are annoying because they don't understand the rules. Yet the rules limit what newbs can do - so in a way they are counter productive to newbs learning how to use this site productively.

I have now answered 10 questions on SO, including the original one I asked, but of that 10, 8 of the OP's haven't even come back to review their questions.

My question then is twofold - should the limit for raising comments be lowered or removed? Or should there be a mechanism for an experienced reviewer to identify the Answer or Edit (provided by a newb) is a comment - and allow them to generate the comment on behalf of the person providing the Answer/Edit.

Comment: Do you have links to your deleted answers? The reputation limit **should not** be lowered. Finally, when I come across a comment that was posted as an answer, I'll sometimes leave the comment on behalf of that person.

Comment: Yesterdays answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856192/why-am-i-receiving-a-java-io-ioexception-in-this-loop/24856487#24856487). I would have liked to leave as comment initially, but had to leave as Answer.

Answer (score 16):

The reputation restriction is there for a reason. We need you to understand how the site works, and the best way to ensure that for relatively new users is to set a reputation restriction for comments so you will learn how reputation works, as well as how exactly to earn that reputation; namely, by asking answering questions, and making appropriate edits.

By using edits to force your comments on other people's posts (and in a place where they don't belong), you're trying to circumvent that restriction, as well as abusing edits. Please don't do that. Edits should only be used for their intended purpose.

Should the limit for raising comments be lowered or removed? Certainly not removed because otherwise that gives brand new users free reign to abuse the site with spam or nonsensical comments, which are *incredibly difficult* to moderate compared to questions and answers, and I'm not sure how much we could possibly lower it for it to make an impact, considering that each question upvote awards 5 reputation, each answer upvote awards 10, and each answer acceptance awards 15, which makes it already pretty easy to earn this reputation through participating on the site normally.

Comment: The Edit that got Rejected was removing a redundant piece of code from the answer and it got a 2-3 vote in the end. 2 Approved. 3 who Rejected all stated "should be comment.", but I can't "comment" so how can I help?

Comment: @simo.3792095 you're just 7 reputation points away from being able to make comments. Go make 4 edits to improve other people's posts, or get an upvote on an answer.

Comment: agree @cupcake, but as I stated originally of the 9 questions (on other people's posts) I have provided answers for only 1 OP has come back and reviewed their question (ie no further answers, comment, edits etc) and most of them were recent.

Comment: @simo.3792095 look for more questions to answer?

Comment: I really don't see why comments should be harder to moderate than answers. In either case, you need someone to flag the inappropriate comment/answer. Similarly, why would a spam filter from a comment box be different than one for an answer box? This is obviously some sort of artificial design flaw in the SO design. I've posted a different answer, since I believe the 50 rep rule is nothing but harmful.

Comment: @Lundin for example because there's no review queue on comments.

Comment: @TomášZato There is no review queue for _posting_ question/answers either. Just a "first post" review which is evidently a very ineffective way from keeping crap out.

Comment: @Lundin There's several queues for questions and answers. Comments are only reviewed by moderators, which is problem due to limited ammount of moderators.

Comment: @TomášZato Yet the site is constantly flooded with crap, so review queues is evidently not a good solution for anything. A good system stops the crap _before_ it hits the site.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found a link to the same question - but asked from a reviewers point of view.  It received IMO a much more positive feedback and also an actual answer to the second part of my question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258533/3792095).  Whether or not my specific Answer or Edit would have fallen into this category is a debate for personal opinion, but I am happy that there is at least the ability for reviewers to "fix" the problem and also assist newbs to learn how SO works.

I have also found the detailed explanation of the reasons for the limit as it stands on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)

Comment: I am not disputing the voting mechanism, but how does someone disagree that I have found the answer to my own question - who better to know my question than me??

Comment: I agree to this point. What even looks estranging to me is, that here on the Meta-SO that having an own opinion, which is not the belief of others result easily into a storm of negative votes. I also find there is a trolling trait in this discussion, even when simo.379209 accepted the SO rules.

Comment: In general a questioner could mistakenly believe they had found the answer to their own question. Forced example: Q: Should I write "their hats, not bats" or "there hats, not bats" A: It looks like I should say "there hats, not bats" (but the answer should be "they're hats, not bats")

Answer (score -9):

The comment reputation limit is ***not*** there for any rational reason and all it does is to flood the SO site with crap, that would otherwise possibly have been fine comments.

Almost every new user who is smart enough to realize that what they wish to communicate is not a valid answer, but a comment, find themselves blocked out. New users, smart or dumb, will find a way through the block by posting an answer or making a vandalism edit to someone else's post.

It is therefore incredibly common with low-quality answers such as "sorry this is really a comment but I haven't got the rep...". Similarly, edits that attempt to answer a question are also very common.

For each such answer/vandalism edit, the following people have to get involved:

- The confused low rep user, spending time understanding why they can't comment and then coming up with a work-around that is frowned upon.
- *n* people reading the post and flagging it for moderation as it is not appropriate.
- 5 high rep users who have to do the low-quality or edit review.

Result:

- Instead of having new user A communicating a helpful comment to user B, we have user A annoying *5+n* other users who are probably not interested in what user A was going to communicate.
- While user B, who would have appreciated the helpful comment, is left in the dark, oblivious to the help they were about to receive.
- New user A is annoyed at the poor reception they got on Stack Overflow and will possibly refrain from coming back to the site.
- The 5 veteran users had their time wasted.

I suppose the rationale for this 50 rep rule was to avoid spam and low-quality comments. Such comments would perhaps have to get deleted. But all the rule does in reality, is to move low-quality comments into answers/questions where they belong even less. Or worse: it turns high-quality comments into low-quality answers or vandalism edits.

To increase the usefulness and quality of Stack Overflow, I propose that the 50 rep comment limit should get removed.