# Dissecting a specific instance of an unwelcoming complaint

Tags: discussion, comments, welcoming, unfriendly-or-unkind

Here's an interesting situation I came across recently that I thought could be an object lesson in what is wrong with Stack Overflow these days. (None of this is particularly new, but examples help to concretise problems.)

A new user, let's call them Alice, posted the following as an **Answer** below a question:

> Hi *$userName*; could you add the code you are working with now so we have an idea as to how to help you? — Alice

Another user, let's call them Bob, commented:

> This is the Answer section. Do not ask questions of the poster here. Please delete this. — Bob

Alice responds:

> Bob, I am trying to help by answering the question. I noticed this question got a downvote already so I hoped to actually help instead. I don't yet have the ability to comment so I didn't have any alternative to ask for clarification. — Alice

Bob responds:

> There are reasons you aren't able to comment and it gives you no permission to put comments or questions here. Please delete this. — Bob

Alice later posted this on Meta:

> [..] Here I was trying to contribute to this forum when I made the horrendous mistake of asking for clarification of a brand new user question. I got rude comments from a decade long user constantly asking Me to delete my response. I flagged his comment and now I have even less privileges than I started with! How am I supposed to feel welcomed? I don’t want to post anything in fear that it will be downvoted or randomly be subjected to abusive comments that get deleted? Right now it just feels like there is no room for me here.

<sub>(All these posts have been removed in the meantime.)</sub>

## Dissection

- Alice's intentions were to help the original user; perfectly laudable.
- Bob's first reply was terse, very matter-of-fact. It includes polite phrasing (*"please"*).
- Alice's reply shows she was aware of the commenting restriction and decided to ignore it, albeit with noble intentions. She doesn't remove her "answer".
- Bob's second reply is still very matter-of-fact, but can certainly start to feel hostile. Still contains polite phrasing.
- Alice's Meta post seems a bit hyperbolic without context:

  - plays down her ignoring of the commenting restriction as "horrendous mistake"
  - it doesn't matter how long Bob has been around, but somehow it appears to feel relevant to Alice
  - two comments hardly constitutes "constantly"
  - it's unclear what "less privileges" means exactly
  - "abusive" is a strong word for matter-of-fact comments
- Alice thinks of Stack Overflow as a "forum".
- Alice *fears* downvotes.

## Conclusions

1. Bob certainly could have phrased that a lot better. That is indisputable. However, depending on Bob's English language ability, that was maybe the best he could do. At the very least it sounds like he didn't intend to spend too much time on the topic and was typing only the minimum necessary.
2. None of this would have happened if Alice hadn't ignored the commenting restriction.
3. The commenting restrictions may contribute to people feeling unwelcome as a "systemic problem". Perhaps it should be rethought whether it's still necessary as is; or it needs to be communicated more clearly through improved UX that answers aren't a substitute.
4. The system as such may be too arcane to be easily accessible to new users, which makes it unwelcoming. At the very least it's too easy to mistake it for a regular "forum", which it isn't.
5. One of the most basic principles of the system, downvotes, stirs negative emotions in users.
6. We need to see the entire context before taking anyone's word for what exactly is "unwelcoming".

To me it seems that something like 80% of this problem is "systematic", as in, by design of the site. Bob's second less-than-smooth comment was the trigger, but it wasn't the core problem. Would you agree, or draw different conclusions? What specifically could be changed to prevent this exact situation from occurring again?

Comment: Bob in this scenario sounds polite and is sticking to the point. The hostility is from Alice and her attitude with breaking the rules. Was the original reason for the rep requirement for commenting to prevent spam?

Comment: The only thing that Bob could have done better was linking to the relevant parts of the help center, in particular [How to Answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and possibly [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on commenting.  Although Alice *should* have already read these, it at least allows her to see that Bob's response is backed by the community guidelines.

Comment: Oh wow, I remember that meta post. _Those_ were the "rude" comments? I tried to give them an encouraging reply iirc, but I assumed from their tone that the rudeness was a bit more than that.

Comment: Maybe an answer wizard could direct newbies on how to answer properly.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's.... basically what keeps on happening. New user thinks "please delete this" is hostile and unwelcoming. They come here saying we're all out to get them. We then happen to see the comments/interactions, and most of us go "huh?" cause whatever was implied to be there is..... nowhere to be found :/

Comment: I am just BAFFLED that the general consensus seems to be that Alice is the "bad guy" here...

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate I'm sorry no. The consensus seems to be "both parties have their faults". That's what I personally think. Bob was a bit abrasive and could definitely be better. But Alice is also saying "I know this isn't by the rules, but I'll do it anyway, and when I get called out for it, I'll say the person telling me is rude and harassing". Don't you see Alice's hyperbole a little bit here? That's what I personally find sad. People come here and go *I WAS ABUSED*. Then when we look.... it's not that. That false discourse does **nothing** to help bridge gaps between people.

Comment: @Devil I’d formulate it as Alice’s well intentioned actions clashing with the design of the system. Her fault was not learning and/or ignoring how the system works. The system’s fault was not accommodating well meaning users like her. Bob’s fault was not displaying the necessary finesse while commenting, or that he commented in the first place.

Comment: I've long thought it odd that commenting isn't available as an immediate privilege, but answering is. I don't see how spam is the reason considering that could be posted as a question or answer where it'd likely gain way more visibility.

Comment: Why did Bob not just flag as "not an answer", downvote, post a single comment and move on? Life would have been easier.

Comment: ^^Yes, that's what I do. The "system" does eventually remove such "answers" within a reasonable amount of time. When (if) I comment in such situations I merely mention that the Answer box is only for answers. When something like this hits the NAN queue there's a canned response about comments, as I recall, so no need for an individual to write that.

Comment: @MichaelBerry that's the thing - questions and answers get A LOT of visibility. The lifetime of spam posted as such tends to be minutes and sometimes even less than a minute. A comment, by comparison, is a perfect vector for advertising, since they get a lot less attention from moderation and curation point of view.

Comment: @VLAZ Surely that also makes it less of a target for spammers though, since far fewer people will ever see it? I could be wrong, but I can't help but wondering if we're restricting them because of a problem that may well not exist.

Comment: @MichaelBerry what is better - spam shown for, say, 2 minutes that is viewed by a dozen people or spam shown for potentially weeks or months and potentially to hundreds of people? And remember I said more visibility *for curation and moderation*. Not "it's totally invisible* but there are *more* tools we have to deal with spam - review queues will pick up spam posts (triage, first posts, late posts), normal readers of posts who follow activity will see and vote/flag, too. Any post is put under a lot more scrutiny for potentially "bad" content where "bad" doesn't just mean spam.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Comments? We don't really bother with curating them. Some get upvotes occasionally, others might attract flags but as long as the comment 1. isn't hurtful 2. appears to be at least somewhat on-topic, then it stays. So you can easily mask spam by saying something trivial like "I had this problem, check here <link>" or even just "Check out this library <link>" and these are very inlikely to be flagged or flagged quickly. Not enough eyes on them looking for spam. [See here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: You're the mod, just shoot Alice, and put Bob to jail. That's how those situations were handled in the past. But, but ... new alices are coming in, and bobs will get out of the jail. Maybe we need a SO Academy, a ten hours video teaching how people do their way at SO (ten hours – the same time it currently takes to find and read all the rules applied here). Then the final exam, B required  before you can contribute at SO in any way. If you won't pass the exam, you're welcome to try again on the next season, with a fresh attitude, and keen on learning.

Comment: Bob's mistake was commenting. Flag as NAA, should be deleted within a couple minutes. If alice keeps doing that they'll eventually be answer-banned, if not then there's no issue here. There are automated systems in place to deal with such things without going into personal interaction that can be perceived as unfriendly.

Comment: If we disregard that Bob could flag instead of commenting, this situation happened because Alice and users like her either don't know about rules or intentionally break rules because they want to help. The core issue here is that Alice probably would not  try to breaking the rules if she knew that breaking rules comes with potential punishment - answer ban. Same goes for poor questions, people just don't know about ban.

Comment: @Dalija Looking at it through the lens of [meta-tag:welcoming], the threat of punishment isn't really the solution. Even without that particular lens, it would probably be preferable to enable people to help instead of enforcing that they can't.

Comment: It is chicken or egg problem... telling about punishment is not welcoming, without telling them makes people start using site unprepared and that almost always ends up with a lot of frustration... and feeling unwelcome.

Comment: I agree with deceze. I answer or comment in order to help. Being prevented from doing so — or (as has been discussed elsewhere) not being allowed to post links or images — makes the site feel unwelcoming and less useful as a teaching resource. It's like having your fingers slapped by the headmaster when you pin a helpful note to the school noticeboard. It's especially unwelcoming when you know you're an expert and could help, were it not that your ability _as proxied by reputation_ won't let you. Reputation is a poor way to measure the worth of contributions.

Comment: @Phil Reputation is a pretty sure way to avoid comments by anonymous spam accounts, but 1) it also has a high false positive rate and 2) it’s not entirely known how many spam comments we *would* get without this restriction, so, yeah… maybe it should be rethought.

Comment: I don't think anyone has answered this: would the Alice-and-Bob situation be worse or better were Alice's answer allowed to remain? A variant example might clarify. Assume $userName asks about an algorithm coded in Fortran 66. Alice wants to advise him that more people will understand it if he recodes in Fortran 2008. Stack Overflow won't let her comment, so she posts her advice as an answer. Now, is it more helpful to retain that answer, or delete it? Keeping it helps Bob, who revises to a better question, which attracts answers, which help other readers. Deleting it — helps whom?

Comment: @Phil The existence of “answers” 1) makes the question less interesting to people looking for unanswered questions and 2) signals that a solution to the problem posed can be found there by people looking for a solution to the same problem, which then leads to disappointment and wasted time when it turns out the answer is none.

Comment: @deceze. Good point. So what you said in another comment still holds: "design the system around people that stewards them in the right direction better".

Answer (score 57):

I think one problem with comments like that are that people are using the wrong tool for the job. Bob could have just flagged the answer as NAA without commenting. That looks like a very straightforward non-answer that would have had no trouble getting deleted as a result of that flag.

From my observations, trying to get someone to delete their post with comments rarely works, and results in an unpleasant exchange more often than not.

Second thing Bob could have done is to not comment again after Alice declined to remove the answer. The initial comment is informative, but if the person does not take the advice, continuing to argue with them about it is pointlessly negative. Unless you're a moderator, you have no real ability to enforce what you're telling them, so all you can really accomplish with more comments at that point is to escalate the situation.

I think if there's any improvement that could be made to the system to ease interactions like these, it would be to make it easier to delete things that need to be deleted. I assume the reason Bob tried to delete that answer using comments was that he did not think that flagging it as NAA would work. If people had more confidence in the tools intended for that job, maybe they would be less likely to resort to inefficient and uncomfortable methods.

Comment: Bingo; this. Any time you try to solve with a comment what you should be solving with a flag, you're gonna have a bad time. Don't leave a comment telling people their answer is "not an answer"; raise a flag. Don't leave a comment telling people their question is "unclear" or "too broad" or whatever else; just recommend closure.

Comment: @CodyGray Honestly seems a bit weird to me that "a decade long user" wouldn't have already come to that conclusion as well.

Comment: It is regularly puzzling to me, as well. I often find that, in the case of established users being flagged for "unfriendly" behavior, it's a result of their choosing to comment instead of simply (and silently) choosing to downvote and/or vote to close. If you don't leave a comment, you cannot be perceived as hostile. And, you contribute to the *solution*—the removal of inappropriate content. Nobody wants to be part of the precipitate.

Comment: Harsh - and *possibly* unfriendly ... but ultimately pragmatic! Gets the job done, and maintains the 'quality of the site'. (But is that what the powers want?)

Comment: @AdrianMole I sincerely don't see it as harsh. I think it's less likely to hurt someone's feelings if "the system" corrects something that they did wrong rather than another person. I think it removes the confrontational aspect from the NAA deletion. Instead of getting embarrassed or defensive because someone criticizes them, their experience is more like "I tried to do something and it didn't work" which is a much easier pill to swallow IMO. I think without comments involved the level of friendliness depends on how well the system works at informing the user what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Exactly! When I come across such posts these days, I generally add the NAA flag **without** comment - then the OP just sees it as "the system." From experience, adding any comment (even a stock reply) makes the new user think that it's **me** who's the bad guy - and can sometimes start a potentially unpleasant exchange. Which is why I think that an 'auto' (and anonymous) move-to-comment flag may be useful ... sometimes.

Comment: While i agree with the answer about not using comments to communicate this kind of stuff - there is one problem that does fall into the "unfriendly" side from Alice's perspective.  Her "answer" gets deleted without warning or reason and without feedback.  I don't know the answer to solving that problem other than system generated comments or notifications pointing "Alice" to the correct place in the documentation on how to best use the site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I completely agree that people need to be properly informed when their posts are deleted, but I don't see why system generated comments or notifications couldn't take care of that sufficiently. To be honest, I don't really know whether or not they actually do at this point, but it seems like an important feature that would not be very difficult to implement. (Easy for me to say, I know)

Comment: Even if Bob had raised a flag, wouldn't an identical exchange have started with the automatically generated "this does not provide an answer to the question" comment from the Low Quality Posts review queue?

Comment: @pppery it's possible. I've actually always doubted whether the autocomment at that point is really useful or appropriate. It seems to me that if the flag is still in review, whether or not it provides an answer hasn't really been settled yet, so the fact that the system automatically comments to that effect on behalf of the reviewer is jumping the gun a bit. I think it might be better if it waited until the review was complete and applied a message to the post as it was deleted so the OP understood what happened.

Comment: There's really no need for a conversation. Either it really is NAA as determined by the flag review, and the OP gets a system generated message to that effect when it's deleted, or it is _not_ NAA as determined by the flag review, and the OP doesn't hear about it at all. Of course that's assuming people review properly, but that's a different issue ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray: I only slightly disagree with this: "Don't leave a comment telling people their question is "unclear" or "too broad" or whatever else; just recommend closure." - If you can point out what is unclear by asking for clarification on a specific point, or if you can point out how it is too broad (e.g. by suggesting that secondary questions be edited out and asked separately), then such a comment can still be helpful. Beyond that, I agree with Don't Panic's and Makoto's answers to this meta; effectively just saying "don't do this" isn't what comments are meant for.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes, if you can provide *specific, additional details* about how to improve a particular question, then a comment is fine. But that comment needs to go above and beyond what is stated in the close reason, otherwise it's just noise.

Comment: @CodyGray: I definitely agree with that :)

Comment: This answer and comments assume deletion is what the flag will lead to.  Alternatively - something I've seen plenty, and why I would comment and flag - is that the mod that handles it converts the answer to a comment, Alice learns nothing, and continues making the same "mistake".  Bob was probably just trying to circumvent that.

Comment: @Izkata I believe the system that handles deletion by votes should inform the poster of what happened and why it happened so they at least have the _opportunity_ to learn from their mistake. If it doesn't, in my opinion the vote to delete feature is missing a necessary piece of functionality. If a mod converts an answer to a comment I believe they are able to send a message to the poster. I don't know if they always do; I assume that can vary depending on the circumstance. Most non-answers like that that I've seen aren't really worth converting to comments anyway in my opinion.

Answer (score 19):

Alice doesn't do herself any favors by blithely ignoring the restriction for posting comments.

Bob doesn't do himself any favors by continuing to engage after his initial comment.

[The root of the issue then becomes comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367562/addressing-the-highest-friction-point-of-seeming-welcoming-heavily-rate-limitin#comment586954_367562).  People use them for far more than they should be used for, and people genuinely *misunderstand* what purpose they're meant to serve.

What could be changed here?  Two things; one is more cultural, and the other is more technical.

The *cultural* change is to flag an answer after seeing that it's not answering the question, or that it's an attempt at a comment.  Commenting ***exactly once*** to the effect gives you the platform to inform someone that they're not using this feature as it was intended, and the flag allows a janitor to come along and clean up the mess before it really gets too bad.

Good luck; people get really set in their ways and while they're not *technically* in the wrong, two wrongs don't make a right.

The *technical* change would be to just nuke comments outright.  ***We*** can't be considered rude or hostile or "toxic" if ***we*** aren't the ones commentating.  It also removes ambiguity.  If your "answer" isn't an answer, it gets downvotes and (potentially) removed from the site, reinforcing the notion that ***answers*** are answers, and comments aren't.

Comment: With no comment there's no feedback loop and people won't be able to improve neither :/

Comment: The *platform* needs to provide the feedback loop, @Tensibai.  Comments aren't good enough because they have such room to be abused (as per above).

Comment: I fail to imagine how the platform could cover all feedback/clarification questions, I'm missing an alternative way for an improvement feedback loop to be convinced that removing comments would improve things overall

Comment: @Tensibai:  What, realistically, do you need to *say* to a bad question?  There's about five or six major reasons why a question gets closed or downvoted, and that's often enough information to get someone to fix their issue.  Do you have an example of what *else* you'd want to add besides, "Please include your full code an an applicable error message", "This question is off topic because X", etc. ?

Comment: A proper question I answered lately, had mcve but was just lacking a small precision, it was answerable as is but talking with the OP lead to a helpful answer for the real task instead of just an answer matching the question, I think that's my only answer this year so not that hard to find :)

Comment: I see that answer @Tensibai - [I presume it's this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59946126/1079354).  Gonna be blunt - comments aren't meant for long back-and-forth either.  That would be a better use case for chat; if someone *wanted* to give that kind of detailed information they could voluntarily open up a chat window.  Comments are definitely ***not*** meant for long conversations or long debug sessions.

Comment: Indeed, chat is sadly too much out of line from the q/a and doesn't work that well for async communications, specially as you don't get notice as you get under an a'swer if someone just talk in a room without pinging you (or if they ping you after 48h because week end, etc)

Comment: I’m becoming more and more in favor of doing away with comments in some way or another too. And chat too, while we’re at it. Those seem to be the largest sources of discontent really. No wonder, since it lets humans interact; and we’ve seen where that goes… 

Comment: @deceze I think you'd find (at least in the tags I cover) so few questions would get answered that the site would be perceived as *really* unwelcoming. The vba tags get so many non-professionals who have no idea what information is important. And even professionals often have too little knowledge of the Office application's behavior and don't know where to start. Killing off the feedback loops would be a poor way to approach things...

Comment: @Tensibai: I do agree that comments can help suggest improvements or request clarification, though I also think that comments shouldn't be used to leave unhelpful responses like "delete this" or get into arguments when the initial feedback is ignored. It's reasonable for an initial comment to (politely) explain "Answers shouldn't be used to comment on the question" just in case OP is unaware of how SE works, but it's not productive to get into arguments when OP ignores that feedback.

Answer (score 19):

> This is the Answer section. Do not ask questions of the poster here. Please delete this. — Bob

I'm baffled at the number of people who seem to think this is polite.

> This is the Answer section.

This implies that Alice was too stupid to realize for herself that she was posting an answer, not a comment.

> Do not ask questions of the poster here.

Bob is giving orders.  Do you take it well when someone you don't know gives you orders?

> Please delete this.

It seems like the "Please" is what's making people think this is polite, but by the time the Please rolls around, the damage is already done.  "Please delete this" is also terse and unhelpful.

In addition, the entire comment doesn't give any indication of what the poster should do instead.  The whole thing basically says "You don't know what you're doing.  You screwed up.  Undo it."

If that's polite and helpful, I'd shudder to see what passes for unkind and unhelpful around here.

Comment: I don't think a majority of people here are saying it's *polite* per se, but it's not purposefully trying to be *abusive* either. It's not *saying* "you don't know what you're doing, you screwed up" or anything like that. It basically cites rules. That in itself isn't abusive or anything, it's just facts. The fact that Bob included a "please" signals to me that he's *trying* to be somewhat neutral and polite about it, even if he's arguably failing at it.

Comment: I agree that it isn't _abusive_; Bob doesn't go off on a racist rant or abject name-calling.  But I find it impossible to see the message we're discussing as _polite_.

Comment: I'm simply putting on my internet-tinted-communication glasses here. We have no idea where Bob is from or what level of verboseness counts as polite there. If I read this in an old-Russian-guy accent for example, it loses a lot of its edge. *"Dis is Anser sekshon. Do not ask question of postr here. Please delete dis."*  As long as it's not overtly impolite, I'll give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @deceze I think there is a very good reason the management frequently use the word "unwelcoming" when discussing the experience for new users: you're absolutely right that this comment is not "abusive", and may be well-intentioned, but it doesn't take a lot of empathy to understand it would feel **unwelcoming**. That's not too say it's Bob's *fault*, but if the system can help avoid Bob even needing to write that comment, then Alice, who also had good intentions, won't receive that unwelcoming message.

Comment: @IMSoP Yup, pretty much my entire point here. You can bang the drum about being welcoming as long as you want, as long as you have free form comments you’ll *always* get into situations like this, no matter everyone’s intentions. So instead of trying to fix people, which clearly hasn’t worked the past decade, design the system around people that stewards them in the right direction better.

Answer (score 14):

> Alice's reply shows she was aware of the commenting restriction...

**It only shows she knows she can't comment.** It does not imply that she understands why or that she's aware of the rules for answer posts. Assuming that every user who's tried to comment and gotten an error message also knows the rules is a mistake.

A common problem with new users is that they're not aware that the moderation here goes beyond just stopping spammers, trolls, and other bad actors. Alice thought that using the answer section to get clarification was OK because she wasn't being malicious. It's also why we keep getting people protesting their question being closed with, "It's a legitimate question". The idea that content that isn't actively harmful can still be against the rules doesn't occur to them because that isn't how other Q&A sites work.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to *make* people realize the rules are different here.

I think if you're going to leave a comment on an answer like this from a new (or just low rep) user, you should just explain that there are rules against this and the consequences for breaking them. Something like,

*I realize you don't have enough rep to comment, but it's against the rules to use answer posts for anything other than answering. It can get your post down voted and deleted (and even get you answer banned if it keeps happening).*

> it's unclear what "less privileges" means exactly

There are six privileges a user earns before reaching the "comment everywhere" privilege at 50 rep. Assuming she got down votes on her non-answer, she lost enough reputation to lose at least one of those privileges.

Comment: Maybe even add your text suggestion as automatic guidance (ie a visible warning box) when a low rep user clicks to write an answer: "I realize you don't have enough rep to comment, but it's against the rules to use answer posts for anything other than answering. It can get your post down voted and deleted (and even get you answer banned if it keeps happening)."

Answer (score 12):

One *possible* action Bob could have taken was to offer to 'transfer' Alice's answer to a comment, or even just done so (I've done this on a *very few* occasions). In fact, one of the 'stock replies' provided by the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) user-script is exactly this:

> This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, you will
>   be able to post comments. For the moment I've added the comment for
>   you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

My problem with this is that it *could* be seen as an 'abuse' of the system, in order to bypass privilege requirements.

Perhaps better would be to make it easier for non-moderators to convert such answers to comments? I am aware that mods can do this quite easily - perhaps there should be a specific flag for such 'non-answers' that could trigger such an action? I have also heard, in chat rooms, IIRC, that *some* answers are 'automagically' converted to comments, but I know very little else about this mechanism.

I also seem to recall that the idea of removing (or, at least, lowering) the 50-rep requirement for making comments has been discussed here on Meta recently.

Connected Meta discussions:

- [How to handle answers that should be comments but the answerer doesn't have enough reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258530/10871073)
- [Privilege to convert deleted answer to comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268820/10871073)

Comment: I do not particularly care for the recommendation that you "convert" another user's answer into a comment. There's no real way of doing that: the comment will always appear as being posted by you, so that's confusing. And adding in a bunch of meta-commentary about how this was originally incorrectly posted as an answer by user X, which has now been removed, but I'm leaving this comment just in case it conveys useful information...meh. **Flag the non-answer as NAA, and moderators will convert it to a comment if it conveys any useful information; otherwise, we'll delete it.**

Comment: @Cody I think you’re misunderstanding the suggestion here. I think the proposal is to make the moderator “move to comment” functionality (indirectly) accessible to regular users, e.g. like a spam flag.

Comment: That's what the second half of the answer suggests, yes, @deceze, but I was commenting on the first half of the answer. I had planned to mention the second half of the answer, too, but by the time I got done writing the comment, I was out of characters, and didn't feel like submitting a second one. :-) Yeah, I wouldn't be opposed to allowing a quorum of flaggers to auto-convert an answer to a comment. At the same time, I'm not sure it's urgently necessary. There are still enough moderators to do this.

Comment: @Cody I cannot disagree - the reason I tried to make clear that I have 'done this' on only a **very few** occasions is exactly the point you made - it becomes a meta-comment, or "comment-by-proxy" - which is a road (IMHO) we should avoid. I was actually thinking a while back about raising a Meta question on how best to handle such 'moved to a comment' actions (as suggested by the auto-comment plug-in); it's far from ideal, but I offered the 'answer' by way of discussion.

Comment: ... but - just maybe - adding some kind of flag-quorum to do what only the moderators can currently do would be a step to help relieve the (ever increasing?) mod-flag queues?

Answer (score 12):

> What specifically could be changed to prevent this exact situation from occurring again?

Fix the root cause: give better guidance to question authors on how to ask and what is expected, this has good chances to solve 80% of the problematic posts (questions AND answers which are not really answers, this include comments as answer as well as "guesses" answers).

Getting more "in shape" questions would cut off a lot of terse responses triggered by a repeat fatigue in my opinion.

[Related idea of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370270/3627607) from the question wizard prototype along the others to get it more effective back at that time.

Comment: Your answer relates to **questions**....the issue here is **comments** being posted as **answers**.

Comment: @Paulie_D which are a direct consequence of unclear questions, I propose to get a step upward and work on the root cause of comments as answers instead of working around comments as answer only

Comment: You can add all the guidance you want, but you can't make people read it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm well, it works for 80% of the cases on github, gitlab, jira and all others systems I've seen. Getting templates do improve the quality of the issues/FR/ideas and give the author more confidence what they're writing match the expectations. I've observed snark in issue reception going down on various projects after templates have been put in effect.

Comment: We need an answer a question wizard!

Comment: We have a question answering wizard. We call him Jon Skeet. @Trilarion

Answer (score 9):

While I agree with several of the answers here in whole or in part about the users and who is at fault, I think the best solution to this problem *by far* lies with point #3:

> The commenting restrictions may contribute to people feeling unwelcome as a "systemic problem". **Perhaps it should be rethought whether it's still necessary as is**; or it needs to be communicated more clearly through improved UX that answers aren't a substitute.

(emphasis mine)

We probably ought to have an experimentation period where users with 10 rep can comment on *questions* anywhere, but still require 50 rep to comment on answers other than their own. Of the **8600+** comment flags I've raised on Stack Overflow, I see and flag **way** more unnecessary comments under answers than I do under questions anyway.

Most of the situations where someone comments unnecessarily under a question, there's a better chance the question is going to be closed or deleted anyway, as there are more avenues to getting rid of questions than there are to getting rid of answers.

I suspect this would have the benefit of practically annihilating the phenomenon of answering with a request for clarification (which is so common that there's even a prescribed option for it in the VLQ review queue), while still preventing low-rep users from commenting "+1", "thanks", or "awesome answer!" under answers before hitting the 50-rep threshold.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion is a corollary to Lundin's answer: better onboarding for new users. Add a basic tutorial with a multiple choice quiz, prompted upon account creation (though optional) to get the ability to comment (maybe in parallel with the rep path?). There are so many common mistakes that new users make, it feels pretty easy to ask basic questions to make sure that users know the ropes.

Suggested questions include:

- If I need to respond to answers with an additional line of code/function referenced, what should I do?
- Ok, so let's say I need to add a LOT of code (200+ lines, multiple files), what should I do?
- If I really appreciate an answer or question, what should I do?
- If an answer on someone else question nearly solves my problem, but it's not exactly the answer or it doesn't work for my problem, what should I do?

Etc. You get the point. Not sure if this is worth the resources to develop (I'd want to make it bot resistant), but it'd definitely solve this and a few other problems, while still maintaining a barrier to entry.

Maybe make it so the tutorial is available from the start, but the "quiz" isn't until you have positive rep, if we want to make the barrier stronger.

Comment: The complaint the quiz suggestion always gets is that if the Q&A is static it can be cheated. I think a quiz should include audits from Triage and Low Quality Posts. That way the questions always change and the user has to have some understanding of site rules to pass it.

Comment: I don’t think putting up more and more complicated blocks is the answer. If anything, the site’s design/interaction model/features need to be tweaked to naturally lead users into the desired behavior.

Comment: A couple references as the quiz idea has been floated before, although for questions (see their duplicates too): [Programming Quiz to be able to ask questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337423/7795130), [A tiny barrier to entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254194/7795130)

Comment: @deceze I think there are limits to what we can do there. For example, it'll always be easier to link to a github page instead of formatting code into a MVCE. I do agree though: it should be harder to do the wrong thing.

Comment: The Tour is very short and I forgot all about it a week later. I'm not Alice, but used an Answer for clarification. No malice intended. I find a lot of things here very confusing and taking a quiz would be welcomed. I'm not finding a lot of "naturally leading" things here. I spend a lot of time looking for links to answers about conduct and general practice and it's somewhat discouraging that so much effort needs to go into just finding out the "rules". Sometimes there are no links to find, other times there's two full pages of posts to dig through.

Comment: I sort of agree with deceze here... That said, I would also recommend that if people do post comments explaining why a certain behavior should be avoided, it helps to link to the relevant help page or meta post that explains it. Then it makes it clearer that a certain approach is site/network policy, not just one random commenter being upset with you.

Answer (score 5):

Bob's comments weren't *rude*, but they were the problem here, IMO.

That Alice reacted so poorly and that originally "broke the rules", is a distraction. Yes, Alice reaction is awful and does not help matters. Yes, Alice shouldn't have disregarded the rules "just because".

But Bob's comments were not necessary nor useful, and triggered the whole unpleasantness. We have tools in place to deal with Alice breaking the rules.

A "Not an answer flag" is all that was needed. Even coupled with a downvote, to help drive the message home.

We need to let the system work instead of engage in fruitless discussions.

We are all "moderators" in the sense that we use the different moderation tools (votes, flags, review queues, etc.) to curate the site. That doesn't mean we are supposed to act as "teachers" for users on how to use the site.

Unless one is *very* good at it (and Bob wasn't) it is very easy those efforts will be poorly received.

And if the one on the receiving end of that unsolicited advise is not particularly sensible and reasonable (and it looks like Alice wasn't), you have a recipe for bad experience for everyone.

TLDR; Less comments. More votes and flags.

Comment: Since “less comments” is hard to enforce culturally as is… any suggestions how to tackle that design-wise?

Comment: @deceze a thing worth a try is to [collapse all comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180752/165773) (after certain age of posts). It probably won't led to immediate but is likely to gradually introduce a culture of avoiding comments when possible (like in your case) - especially for newcomers many of which earn the culture from old popular posts (which are naturally polluted with comments, due to age and popularity)

Comment: @deceze You make a valid point. My answer is rather useless, since it provides no solutions. But I think the only we can do is reiterate this as often as and as clearly as possible. _"Friends, do not comment in vain. Use the tools the system provides. You'll be annoyed now and then. [Let it go](https://youtu.be/L0MK7qz13bU)"._ System-wise, de-emphasizing comments as much as possible. Making them truly ephemeral. But nothing will save us from occasional friction. If not comments, someone will complain about votes, closures or deletions. But we shouldn't make mountains out of molehills either.

Comment: Cannot help but up-vote your answer - as someone who has ('on occasion') engaged with replies to NAA flags + comments. Things can quickly become unpleasant and/or unfriendly without good discipline.

Comment: I must disagree.  Bob was indeed rude.  See my answer below, and Wayne Conrad's as well, for an analysis.

Answer (score 5):

I think the way you frame this situation without just linking to it is fantastic, and a great way to start a discussion.

## Conclusions

> 1. Bob certainly could have phrased that a lot better. That is indisputable. However, depending on Bob's English language ability, that was maybe the best he could do. At the very least it sounds like he didn't intend to spend too much time on the topic and was typing only the minimum necessary.

Bob was in the wrong with his comment.

Users are not supposed to engage in meta discussions on posts. He should have used the applicable flag for that statement and moved on. Alternatively, to be helpful towards Alice, he could have reproduced the sentiment in her comment on the main question if he agreed with it.

> 2. None of this would have happened if Alice hadn't ignored the commenting restriction.

Alice was wrong to answer as a comment, as it was gaming the system in order to still comment. However, she did this only because the system forced her to. There needs to be a way to have some sort of canned requests that users can ask for with questions.

> 3. The commenting restrictions may contribute to people feeling unwelcome as a "systemic problem". Perhaps it should be rethought whether it's still necessary as is; or it needs to be communicated more clearly through improved UX that answers aren't a substitute.

It is still necessary for many reasons other than this situation.

However, this situation is important, and as such there does need to be a way for the UI to be used in a manner which solves the problem and tension this situation creates. For example, there could be a set of canned requests that users can issue which the OP sees and which other users can tell were issued.

> 4. The system as such may be too arcane to be easily accessible to new users, which makes it unwelcoming. At the very least it's too easy to mistake it for a regular "forum", which it isn't.

It still meets many of the definitions of a "forum", just not of what many would call an online bulletin board. Calling it a forum may be a form of naivete but it doesn't necessarily reflect an inability to use the system or that the system is unwelcoming.

> 5. One of the most basic principles of the system, downvotes, stirs negative emotions in users.

[status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design)

A downvote should "shock" users into realizing that something needs to change. Downvotes are direct messaging that there is a problem. Internalizing problems as negative emotions is something that many people deal with on a daily basis, and Stack Overflow is unfortunately not capable of providing the kind of therapy to remediate that.

It was brought into question whether nor not my stance was accurate here. Sure, this is a blunt statement I make, and the word shock never appears to be used during design discussions, so I will admit that my by-design statement was a little harsh. I am going to leave it, as a preface, to this next section.

When designing the exchange, dowvotes were deemed a critical part of of communicating the quality rating of a post. While it wasn't intended to be overtly harsh, both Joel and Jeff were aware after launch that "getting a downvote feels like a slap in the face".

> "In building Stack Overflow, we realized the intrinsic informational value of full range post scores. Downvotes give you the critically important ability to distinguish between the good, the bad, and the ugly. Without downvotes, how can you possibly tell the difference between a post that is harmless but uninteresting, and one that is actually wrong or harmful? Sure, it stings a bit to get downvoted. I’ve been downvoted myself on Stack Overflow. And each time, it makes me pause. But that’s good! That’s necessary! You have to believe there are potential consequences for every post you make — both good and bad. This is how things work on real playgrounds; why would we expect our web playgrounds to be any different?" -[Jeff Atwood (Stack Overflow Co-Founder)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/09/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/)

So, while it was not exactly designed to be a "shock", it was acknowledged as such. Mostly, the system was acknowledged overall as containing some level of anxiety to use.

> "I've heard people describe the process of asking a question on Stack Overflow as anxiety inducing. To me, posting on Stack Overflow is supposed to involve a healthy kind of minor "let me be sure to show off my best work" anxiety:
>
> - the anxiety of giving a presentation to your fellow peers
> - the anxiety of doing well on a test
> - the anxiety of showing up to a new job with talented coworkers you admire
> - the anxiety of attending your first day at school with other students at your level
>
> I imagine systems where there is zero anxiety involved and I can only think of jobs where I had long since stopped caring about the work and thus had no anxiety about whether I even showed for work on any given day. How can that be good? Let's just say I'm not a fan of zero-anxiety systems."
>   -[Jeff Atwood (Stack Overflow Co-Founder)](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/)

> 6. We need to see the entire context before taking anyone's word for what exactly is "unwelcoming".

Sure, however, Bob was unwelcoming here. Users shouldn't be confronting others in comments with meta discussion on main. That is specifically what meta is for.

- On main: use your tools
- On meta: use your words

> What specifically could be changed to prevent this exact situation from occurring again?

Only a feature can prevent this.

Users need a way to provide canned requests for improvements to questions outside of the closure system.

Short of something that facilitates this, we will keep seeing this situation. It would be best if Bob simply flagged and moved on, and if Alice simply did not game the system. That doesn't always happen.

Comment: Why does it need to be outside of the closure system?

Comment: @CodyGray - Users *want* posts to improve, not to close them. However, the only signal currently available is to downvote, close vote / flag, or comment. Many users are simply resigned to the idea that if a post is in bad shape, it will probably end up getting deleted in that same shape. They aren't really wrong either. We need more OP edits. It would make sense to allow for an additional channel of providing feedback prior to closure to get the OP some sort of indication of what might be needed to improve the post. Once closed, reopen stats are very low.

Comment: @CodyGray - Shog once explained to me that when they were first designing feedback mechanisms, users would use whatever was available to indicate low quality, even if that wasn't the intended use, just to send the signal that something was problematic with the post. I think this situation is a prime example of that, and I thought maybe something out-of-the-box would help it improve. That said, my confidence in feature creation is pretty close to 0 at this point, so it was really more of a thought experiment than something seriously considered.

Comment: For the record, I'm not a big fan of *canned* responses, I don't think they do a lot of good. They're too wishy washy to really tell anyone in particular what it is they need to improve. *If* you're going to give any feedback that's supposed to be helpful, it needs to be specific to that particular user and post. Which is obviously a Catch-22 with trying to get rid of freeform comments. Perhaps something like Github's merge request feedback mechanism, where you can leave comments on specific lines of code would be a possible approach…?

Comment: @deceze - I too am not really a fan of canned responses. However, system generated messaging has been somewhat successful in the past. Although, the person writing those is I think hopefully enjoying a nice relaxing whiskey right now. As noted, it was mostly just a wishy washy idea to begin with. Iterations welcome :) Perhaps leaving targeted comments with relation to the issue you mean? Like, "needs more detail", and then under that header a group of comments explaining what details were needed?

Comment: I was about to upvote this when I got to the part about downvotes. The tour describes voting as the mechanism by which the best content floats to the top; it does not say "if you receive a downvote you should feel bad about it", nor does the tooltip on the downvote button say "give this user a shock, if they can't deal with it that's their problem".

Comment: @IMSoP - Thanks for leaving the feedback about that, perhaps it was written a little too harshly with regards to system design. You are correct that downvotes are in principle designed to ensure that the best content bubbles to the top, however, the effect of downvotes is different in practice. Users do internalize downvotes in general, but it was maybe not designed in that fashion. I will have to review a little more and see about making an edit to that section.

Comment: @IMSoP - While it is in not as explicit, that doesn't mean it wasn't essentially part of the design. Please see my edit to that section of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This particular problem boils down to the 50 rep limit to comment.

This limit never made any sense to me, as I already said [back in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306740/584518) and got down-voted into meta hell when I suggested that the limit should be removed. The scenario described in that post is pretty much exactly the one you describe here.

Now from what I've heard from various veterans, the rep limit to comments originally just served to block spammers from posting comments with spam links. That's the original rationale for the 50 rep cap. Also, supposedly the mod tools for comments are worse than what we have for answers.

Unwelcome - status by design.

Comment: Comments don't have any of the safeguards that answers do.  Personally, I think comments ought to get more respect than they do, but at a minimum, users should have an account and maybe 10 earned rep before they can freely post comments.  There has to be *some* barrier to entry.

Comment: I actually agree here. To prevent spam, you could try CAPTCHAs for low-rep users or such. Comments are certainly taken more seriously by people than originally intended, so that entire design should maybe be rethought.

Comment: @RobertHarvey There is no barrier to posting questions and answers, so that isn't much of an argument.

Comment: @deceze When first starting to use SO I wanted to comment as I felt I was really "too new" to offer answers or anything like this, it took a while for me to get to the point of earning rep.  I can only assume most new people wont be willing to wait or some will post low-quality answers in an attempt to earn rep - it seems a little bit of an odd system to me.

Comment: There's no barrier to posting questions and answers because if there were, you'd have a chicken and egg problem.  Can't post comments due to insufficient rep, can't get sufficient rep to post comments. I like @deceze's idea; unqualified users should have to click a recaptcha to post comments.

Comment: I don't know if just straight-up removing the restriction is the best option, but I agree that *something* needs to be done about it.

Comment: re "no barrier to Q or A": True, there is no barrier, but there are consequences. You can get question or answer banned. You cannot get comment banned. Q&A already has a strong metric in place to prevent issues of spam, abuse, etc.

Comment: The commenting restriction is a bit bogus IMHO. I remember being frustrated with that as well when I first started contributing on SO. I never asked any Q's, my only rep was from taking the tour or whatever the typical startup user can get. Certainly an account should be required, and maybe going through the tour/intro (I forget if that's + rep or just the "Informed" badge? either way, the system knows). A captcha would also probably prevent outright spam, and "regular" bad comments can be flagged like normal.

Comment: I don't know what the original motivation was, but today I suspect it does more than that.  I think a plausible fear is that if all limits on comments are removed, then the comment section might devolve to something closer to the Youtube comment section.  Would that actually happen?  I don't know, but I think it's a concern worth thinking about carefully, so talking only about the restriction's use for preventing spam seems to me like it's defeating a strawman.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, both are wrong. Bob could have told Alice once, flagged the answer so a moderator checks it and move on with his life.

But also Alice by doing this:

> Alice's reply shows she was aware of the commenting restriction and decided to ignore it, albeit with noble intentions. She doesn't remove her "answer".

Alice is not following the rules. We all had low reputation, if anyone wants to gain reputation, the best thing to do is to edit questions and answers. When you edit, you gain knowledge on how to ask and how to answer.

> Would you agree, or draw different conclusions? What specifically could be changed to prevent this exact situation from occurring again?

Bob annoyed Alice, that is why Alice felt unwelcomed. But also at the same time Alice is not following the rules. We cannot blame anyone more than the other, but if these are the complains from the people that are feeling unwelcomed then we can only blame the system in this case and not Bob who is trying to follow the rules.

Comment: I think we all mostly agree on those facts, yes. This here was trying to find productive solutions to avoid these situations from occurring.

Answer (score -5):

> There are reasons you aren't able to comment and it gives you no permission to put comments or questions here. Please delete this. — Bob

I am amazed that this is seen as polite by some, and acceptable by many.  This is unfriendly and condescending.  It is the voice of a stern adult talking to a naughty child, not of an experienced user helping an inexperienced one to understand this site's culture and customs.

It is also wrong that one user is directing another to delete their post.  That is, like the tone of voice, Bob assuming authority that Bob does not have.  We don't have the right to go ordering each other around.

Contrast what Bob wrote with what might have been written instead:

> We don't allow comments to be posted as answers here; that's a decision the entire community has made.   I know that's frustrating, especially since you are making a genuine effort to help.  Your desire to help is awesome, something we really want here, and your recommendation is perfect.  Unfortunately, since answers need to be... well, answers... It'll probably be deleted, but please understand that that isn't meant to discourage you or your awesome desire to help.  I hope you will stay, gain reputation, and become a valued member of this community.

Note: I think my suggested replacement is wordier than necessary, but I don't mean for it to be a canonical example.  Just a single instance of what I think a non-condescending version of Bob's post might be.

Comment: You are like me; you think that using more words and being more descriptive is friendlier. However, research and experience suggests that our instincts may be mistaken. People, as a general rule, don’t read and don’t *want* to read. A wall of text is often perceived as inherently hostile, or at least annoying, like a speed bump or flying insect. Further compounding the problem is that non-native speakers, of whom we must be ever cognizant here, may not even be able to understand everything we say and/or may misinterpret the words as unfriendly. Then there’s the issue of character limits...

Comment: @CodyGray I fear you are right.  I don't know how to be perceived as friendly.  I only know how to attempt to be friendly in my own way.  The one thing I am certain of is that Bob is very unfriendly, and almost any attempt to do better would be an improvement.

Comment: @CodyGray By the way, I'm still chewing on your comment.  I am frustrated to learn that what to me was obviously more friendly might actually be less so, and wondering how it is possible to be friendly when anything I say can be taken in ways I don't expect.  I don't know.  I'll keep learning and trying.

Comment: I certainly don't know, either. I don't have the answers. :-) As you said in your first comment, I just keep doing what *I* think makes sense and what I feel is right. That's the best I can do. But yeah, things to chew on. And also to keep in mind that Bob may not have been intending his comment to be unfriendly, so much as to be terse and to-the-point. There's a certain merit to that: it's more likely to be read and understood.

Comment: Bob is factual, neutral & helpful & you have no justification for saying otherwise. You & Alice are shooting the messenger. (Moreover Alice knew they were breaking the rules.) That is the problem, not Bob.

Comment: @CodyGray I would agree with you about people not reading if you were talking about an impersonal system message.  But we're talking about a message from a human being directed at another human being.  There is a need for empathy there, and Bob's terseness didn't show any.

Comment: I also think that Bob's comments are impolite, whether or not he intended them to be. But I also trust the sincerity of many of the people who are saying that they don't find them impolite. That's one reason that I strongly believe that people should use flags rather than comments for this kind of sensitive interaction. There's too much variety in people's perception of politeness to trust them to deliver that kind of message in an unoffensive way, so I think it's best to use the provided tools to deliver the message as neutrally and impersonally as possible.

Comment: FWIW Bob may well have the authority to delete the post given a few helping hands. At 20k Bob can delete vote the answer once it receives a couple downvotes.

Comment: @TylerH He may have shared authority to delete a post.  I don't see how that gives him the authority to order someone else to delete it.

Comment: @philipxy The messenger here is being shot because he's being borderline rude. It's akin to a mailman hand-delivering a package and then making an off-handed comment implying you're too lazy to go pick it up yourself at the post office or something, when you may well be *unable* to go pick it up yourself due to not having a car or something, even though you know a car is needed to go pick up a large package from the post office and transport it home.

Comment: @WayneConrad "please delete it" is a request, not an order. "please" is the crucial bit that makes some people consider it to be a request, and thus polite.

Comment: @TylerH I see the word "Please" there as being pro-forma politeness.  The word "Please" is not magic sauce that makes any utterance polite, nor turns any demand into a request.

Comment: Well, Bob's damned if he does and damned if he doesn't then, isn't he? Don't say please, you're ordering someone to do something. Say please, you're not being sincere. What happened to assuming good intent?

Comment: Your comments are just more unjustified misinterpretation of plain statements, see my 1st comment. But people do that. So the system has to account for it. But the person making plain statements isn't doing anything wrong or avoidable.