# Is "I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation" a valid reason for posting an answer instead?

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503340/1172002) looks to me like a (short) comment, even though it points OP in the right direction. I flagged this as "not an answer", but the flag was declined ("moderator found no evidence to support it").

This is what's recommended in the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258530/how-to-handle-answers-that-should-be-comments-but-the-answerer-doesnt-have-enou), but the fact that the flag was declined makes me wonder whether there's something I've missed about this?

Comment: No, it is never a valid reason. I'm surprised the flag got declined, perhaps a review queue decision?

Comment: I edited out the excuse and the question mark. Still a question and not an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Not a review queue decision - I checked, it's indeed a mod reply as the OP quoted.

Comment: Thats a ridiculously poor answer. It *is* an answer phrased as a question though: "Learn about closures and scoping" would be the "correct" phrasing (still a terrible answer).

Comment: @BoltClock: ah, yes. Time to go home, I'd say, no longer sharp.

Comment: The *question* is poor too. Where did all those upvotes come from?!

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's exactly what I was wondering ;)

Comment: No, but it happens so often that perhaps it would be useful for users with sufficient rep to be able to converte it to a comment and short-circuit the "not-an-answer" deletion ceremony.

Comment: @Magoo: Moderators can do that, but on SO we generally have a policy not to do so unless the user already has enough rep to comment. The last thing we need is regular users misusing such a feature, either destroying otherwise valid short answers or GIGOing crap answers into crap comments.

Comment: @BoltClock : so - moderators have so little to do that community-initiated conversions would not be useful?

Comment: @Magoo: Actually, I have better things to do than entertain strawman arguments.

Comment: Well that escalated fast. One account gone, another put on suspension for voting irregularities.

Comment: Whenever I see _moderator found no evidence to support it_, I just read it as _moderator is in auto-decline mode_.

Comment: It might not be a valid excuse, but we really should rethink if we want to encourage users to leave bad answers instead of comments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some people lead with a statement like that, then go on to leave an actual answer in the sentences that follow. I tend to decline flags in those cases, and remove that initial wording (as Martijn did here). For cases where it really was a comment, I often convert the answer to one.

I think the moderator who reviewed this thought the last part might be a viable answer, and seeing the upvotes decided to not delete it. However, that's not a great answer, and there's something super shady about the voting here. I'm looking into this.

Comment: I already looked at/took care of the voting.

Comment: So to what extent should you try to "interpret" an answer into the comment-ish? In this case in particular it seems to me that you'd be writing the answer for the poster instead of merely a small edit.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - If by removing the initial "I can't comment, but.." the rest could stand as an answer, we tend to do so and not delete the answer. If the remainder really is a comment, I'll still edit that part out and make it a comment if it is worth preserving. I won't touch the rest.

Answer (score 18):

Believe it or not, this is actually *a good thing* - too many folks come in with the notion that they should comment when they *think* they know the answer to a question, reserving answers for cases where they're 100% sure.

The comment rep-restriction forces them to either answer with what they have or do more research until they're sure. And *either one* is preferable to actually commenting.

Even in cases where the author is just kibitzing (they have no idea what the answer is and no intention of trying to provide one), the system offers multiple routes for moderating these answers; comments are comparatively difficult to edit or remove.

In all cases, you should ask yourself these questions when reviewing new answers:

1. Is the answer on-topic and understandable?
2. Does the answer attempt to provide a solution to the problem outlined in the question?

If the answer to both is "yes", then it's an answer - *regardless of whether or not the author would've preferred it to be a comment.*

Comment: My answer to both of your questions would be no, as it was really just a question/hint. Would you have flagged this particular answer?

Comment: I don't opt to edit from the LQP queue often, but when I do, I remove "sorry I can't comment" from actually-somewhat-decent answers.

Comment: It fails, at minimum, #1 @Lars - if you want to be generous and say he was hinting at an answer, then just downvoting is fine, otherwise flag as VLQ.

Comment: So are you saying we should _not_ comment if we think we know the answer but we are unsure?

Comment: If you think you know the answer, @chancea, **then just answer.**

Comment: @chancea An answer that is incorrect is still an answer.  You shouldn't be posting an incorrect (or potentially incorrect) answer as a comment instead.  Of course, if you don't feel that the question contains enough information to be answerable, you can comment with clarifying questions to gain enough information to confidently answer.  A clarifying question belongs as a comment, an answer, even one that's wrong or a guess, is still an answer.

Answer (score 6):

## No!

The purpose of the rep barrier for posting comments is to encourage new users to *watch* and *learn* how the site works before jumping in with their first comments. It's an attempt to prevent them from writing things as comments that shouldn't be comments, for example.

Unfortunately, some people use this as an excuse to go ahead and post their comment in some other, inappropriate/incorrect place. *This is the polar opposite of the desired behaviour*, and I find it incredibly frustrating to be faced with this sort of reverse logic.

That being new is a valid excuse for posting comments as answers is a total myth that just doesn't seem to want to die. It's like saying, "I'm sorry that I have been (and shall continue to) sleeping with your wife behind your back, but I think it's okay because I do not currently have time in my busy schedule to find a girlfriend of my own."

Comment: Your answer seems to say low-rep users shouldn't even be allowed to answer until they have enough rep, am I reading that right?

Comment: @MrLister If I understand correctly, they shouldn't be allowed to create unnecessary noise. SO is commonly confused with an ordinary forum or an online programmer's helpdesk, which increases the amount of unnecessary content. This restriction helps, at least partially, in minimizing that. However, in case of answers, the possible advantage of the site gaining an answer to a question is more important than the cost of handling invalid (in administrative sense) answers.

Comment: @MrLister: Right. If the list of privileges says "you cannot do X until you have Y reputation", then you should not do X until you have Y reputation. You should also not do X in some inappropriate Z manner just because you do not yet have Y reputation. You should wait until you have Y reputation. That's _why_ the site doesn't let you do X until you have Y reputation. It's self-evident that SO didn't add that restriction because they want people to post comments in answers until they get Y reputation, so I don't understand why so many such people think it's acceptable.

Answer (score -5):

I think, the concept of the site is: first, produce worthy content, and then you can chat. :-)

No, it is clearly not a valid reason. People want to comment something, but not having the needed reputation, should first work to collect that.

Getting 50 reputation is very simple, especially because most of the "first-post" reviewers upvote the qualified posts with the intent of motivating the newbie.

*Extension:* Well, maybe on SO it is not so simple, on my experience this site is harder for a beginner. Maybe he could get his first 200 repu on another SE site, and then use his 100 reputation bonus to get an easier start here.

Comment: I struggled more to get the first 50 rep than the rest.

Comment: @DanielDarabos Well, SO is maybe not really friendly, compared to other sites :-( At the beginning there was once that I made around tens of answers without a single reaction.