# How to handle new user's answers that should be comments?

Tags: discussion, new-users, not-an-answer

While making reviews, I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28572703/4170582) (the answer no longer exists) which is not an answer, but I think that this new user did that because he don't have enough reputation to comment.

Normally I should flag it as not an answer, but I am confused if It's fair to do that or not. So, could you please inform me how should I handle that?

Comment: If you think it is unfair to one person then why don't you consider whether it is fair to the dozens of programmers that will visit the question some day and having to read a garbage post?

Comment: @HansPassant Yes thats absolutly true, I was confused on that, but you are right

Comment: See also [Is "I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation" a valid reason for posting an answer instead?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286003)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should still be flagged. The user shouldn't have posted it in the first place.

Not having enough reputation to perform an action does not justify doing the *wrong* thing in order to approximate it.

Note that the post in question isn't even a really good **comment**. The user should just be asking a new question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will flag it and let a comment to ask him make a new question